# "Relative references must start with either" error

Tags: javascript, package

I'm getting this error while importing a package in JS

I tried this:

`Import cloneDeep from './node_modules/lodash-es/cloneDeep.js'`

But it gave me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "./node_modules/baseclone.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: If you've imported lodash into your project you should import it directly via the npm module system, not as a file.

Answer (score 0):

typically in node.js, you dont need to specify the path to the package itself, rather only the package name is needed, and node.js will do the rest. So to import `cloneDeep` from lodash, you would do either:

```
const { cloneDeep } = require('lodash');
```

or

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash';
```

This is only for packages installed through npm, though. If you wanted to import something from another local file that you wrote, you would have to specify the relative path to the file.

```
const {myFunction} = require('./path/to/myFile.js');
```

or

```
import {myFunction} from './path/to/myFile.js');
```